# How to get dust-js helpers working with krakenjs?

Tags: dust.js, kraken.js

I am using krakenjs  for my project which by default uses dust for templating.But I am unable to use dust-js helpers in my project.So,

```
               <td>{name}</td>
```

works fine but

```
            {@eq key=amount value="master"}
                You are no longer a Padawan.  
            {:else}
                You have much to learn, young Padawan  
            {/eq}
```

does not?

P.S.:There is a similar question but answer does not seem to help.[Using dustjs-helpers with Kraken js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24418171/using-dustjs-helpers-with-kraken-js)

Answer (score 1):

By default KrakenJS does not include Dust.js helpers. You have to declare that you want to use them into your config.json. 
Find the section dedicated to dust in your config/confing.json and add "dustjs-helpers" entry to the helpers array. It should look like this if you have also dust-makara enabled:

```
"dust": {
    "helpers": [

        "dust-makara-helpers",
        "dustjs-helpers"


    ]
},
```